# Serializing and deserializing functions to and from JSON

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

Suppose you have the following:

```
function myfunc() {
  // JS code
}

var args = '{ "strfield": "hello world", "numfield": 10, "funcfield": myfunc }';
```

The problem: how do you process the `args` variable before submitting it to the JSON parser so that `myfunc` is replaced with the result of `myfunc.toString()` (that is, the body of the function)? The proposed solution should work on arbitrary functions and such quasi-JSON strings.

Comment: Interesting... but I cannot imagine that there is a way to actually get the code in the body of the function as string. But I can be wrong and if there is way, that would be awesome :)

Comment: Huh? There _is_ such a way: that myfunc.toString() call didn't come out of nowhere :P https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/toString The problem is not getting the function's code, but rather elegantly substituting the fields' value with it without having to mutilate the JSON parser.

Comment: I suppose (assuming `toString` is cross-platform) that you could parse the args string into an object, iterate through every property in the object (recursively), and if the value of any property is defined and is a function, replace it with that function's code, then convert that object back to JSON. The question then becomes, "How do I detect if a JS object is a function?"

Comment: Using `typeof field == "function"`. What you propose would generate a double overhead (and even more, if you compare against native JSON parsers), although it will certainly work... Can you advice any improvements?

Comment: @David: I realize the overhead is large (and no immediate improvements come to mind), but I can't think of any other way. I wouldn't worry about performance until it becomes an issue. And I didn't know about `typeof field == "function"` -- cool!

Comment: Minor nitpick: what is being checked is not JSON, but a Javascript object (its properties). Goal is to produce JSON, but JSON has no concept or value type of function.

Comment: @David Parunakian: Ok, nevermind :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Like this? I had to change it because what you have isn't a valid JSON string since `myfunc` doesn't have double quotes. So I added those.

This parses it, gets the value of `funcfield`, finds the function (although it assumes it is in the global context), calls `toString()` updating the value of `funcfield`, the re-stringifies it as JSON.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/patrick_dw/QUR6Z/

```
var myfunc = function() {
    alert('hi');
};

var args = '{ "strfield": "hello world", "numfield": 10, "funcfield": "myfunc" }';
var parsed = JSON.parse( args );

parsed.funcfield = window[parsed.funcfield].toString();
var stringified = JSON.stringify( parsed );

alert(stringified);
```

Was this what you meant?

---

**EDIT:**

I guess you could use the current context, as long as that context is contained within the context that owns the function.

```
parsed.funcfield = this[parsed.funcfield].toString();
```

Or if you can't double quote the function name, you could use `eval` instead if you're certain the data is safe.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/patrick_dw/QUR6Z/1/

```
var args = '{ "strfield": "hello world", "numfield": 10, "funcfield": myfunc }';
window.eval( 'var parsed = ' + args );

parsed.funcfield = parsed.funcfield.toString();
var stringified = JSON.stringify( parsed );

alert(stringified);
```

Comment: The last version looks good to me (the code is indeed trusted). And in case the name of the field containing the function reference is unknown, I can still traverse the objects (including arrays) found inside the `parsed` object looking for functions... Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

We use the optional second [replacer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_native_JSON#The_replacer_parameter) argument to `JSON.stringify` to preprocess key/values, emitting functions in stringified form:

```
function stringify_with_fns(obj) {
    return JSON.stringify(obj, function(key, value) {
        return typeof value === "function" ? value.toString() : value;
    });
}
```

Then to turn the stringified functions back into real functions on the way out, we use the optional second [reviver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#Example.3A_Using_the_reviver_parameter) parameter to `JSON.parse`, as in

```
function parse_with_fns(json) {
    return JSON.parse(json, function(key, value) {
        if (looks_like_a_function_string(value)) {
            return make_function_from_string(value);
        } else {
            return value; 
        }
    });
}
```

`looks_like_a_function_string` is just a regexp, and the first cut at `make_function_from_string` can use `eval`:

```
function looks_like_a_function_string(value) {
    return /^function.*?\(.*?\)\s*\{.*\}$/.test(value);
}
function make_function_from_string(value) {
    return eval(value);
}
```

To avoid `eval`, we can pick apart the function string to find its arguments and body, so we can pass them to `new Function`:

```
function make_function_from_string(value) {
    var args = value
        .replace(/\/\/.*$|\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\//mg, '') //strip comments
        .match(/\(.*?\)/m)[0]                      //find argument list
        .replace(/^\(|\)$/, '')                    //remove parens
        .match(/[^\s(),]+/g) || [],                //find arguments
        body = value.match(/\{(.*)\}/)[1]          //extract body between curlies

    return Function.apply(0, args.concat(body);
}
```

Testing:

```
x = parse_with_fns(stringify_with_fns({a: function() {var x=1;}}))
x.a
> function anonymous() {var x=1;}
```

Note however that since functions created by `new Function` are all in the global scope, they will lose their enclosing scope and closures.

The only remaining question is whether this is useful. I suppose it might be for small utility functions.

Extending the concept to serializing/deserializing regexps or date objects is left as an exercise.

Comment: Just as an addition: the make_function_from_string function in TypeScript: 
`export function FunctionFromString (value: string) {
   const args = value
      .replace(/\/\/.*$|\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\//mg, '')
      .match(/\(.*?\)/m)![0]
      .replace(/^\(|\)$/, '')
      .match(/[^\s(),]+/g) || []
   const body = value.match(/\{(\s|.)+\}/)![0]
   return Function(...args, body)
}`

Comment: why not just `new Function('return ' + value)()`? works for me