# creating a persistant data hook that supports functions

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, webpack, react-hooks

Ok so I am creating this awesome hook to persist filter state, now some of my filters include not only simple strings that can be saved to local storage and then retrieved but also more complex objects such as dates which in many cases contain functions, the idea is to able to store and then retrieve these functions from local storage.

Here is the hook:

```
export default function usePersistedState(key, defaultValue) {
  let transformedFuncs = parseWithFunc(localStorage.getItem(key))
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(
    () =>  transformedFuncs || defaultValue
  );
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
      if (key){
        localStorage.setItem(key, stringifyWithFunc(state));
      }
  }, [key, state]);
  return [state, setState];
}

function stringifyWithFunc(obj) {
  return JSON.stringify(obj, function(key, value) {
      return typeof value === "function" ? value.toString() : value;
  });
} 

function parseWithFunc(json) {
  return JSON.parse(json, function(key, value) {
      if (isFunction(key)) {
          return transformFunc(value);
      } else {
          return value; 
      }
  });
}

function isFunction(key) {
  switch (key){
    case "toOption":
      return true
    case "transform":
      return true
    case "validate":
      return true
    default:
      return false
  }
}
function transformFunc(value) {
  return eval(value);
}
```

Now I was successful in stringfying all my properties including the functions thanks to the [replacer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON#The_replacer_parameter) option for JSON.stringify that was referenced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4293769/serializing-and-deserializing-functions-to-and-from-json), I was also able to "revive" my functions with the [reviver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#Example.3A_Using_the_reviver_parameter)option for JSON.parse (also referenced above), the issue is that some of the functions I get back in my app from local storage have imported functions (luxon date functions) from webpack, so I get the following error:

```
Unhandled Rejection (ReferenceError): _utils_common__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_11__ is not defined
eval
src/Components/hooks/usePersistedState.js:46
  43 |   }
  44 | }
  45 | function transformFunc(value) {
> 46 |   return eval(value);
  47 | }
  48 |
```

**The issue**: the `eval` is not able to convert or access the `_utils_common__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_11__` this is just a simple shared function in the app.
**Things I tried**: I tried just doing the function locally but still got the same error since I use date transformation functions from luxon which I cannot simply do myself.
**Things I would rather not do**:  Pass my hooks callback functions.
What I am looking for is a way to hydrate/rehydrate my functions from local storage so that I can then go ahead and use them in the app.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive this would work, but I would try making luxon an [external dependency](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/) in webpack:

```
// index.html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/luxon/1.25.0/luxon.min.js"></script>
```

and
then

```
// webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
//...
    externals: {
        luxon: 'luxon'
    }
};
```

Now, when webpack adds 'luxon' as an external, it won't bundle luxon, instead, when you do `require('luxon')` (or however you are handling imports), Webpack will instead return the global luxon.

In theory, since that global will exist in scope, your rehydrated function should still work.

Answer (score 0):

So firstly localstorage don't(can't) know how was the original object. You must  explicitly call JSON.parse().

```
yourObject = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('yourObject'));
```

**NOTE**:

Note that functions are never supported in JSON. So it would not be reliable to reconstruct functions or prototypes from a generated `source code`

1. prototypes aren't captured in JSON and
2. functions may have access to closures.

In order to have rehydrated object prototype, proceed thisway:

```js
// Profile constructor
function Profile() {

}

Profile.prototype.isValid = function () {
  return true;
};

Profile.prototype.isAdmin = function () {
  return this.name === "admin";
};

// create and serialize your object
var profile1 = new Profile();
Profile1.name = "admin";

var copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Profile1));

// rehydrate with functions on prototype
var Profile2 = new User();
for (var prop in copy) {
  if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(copy, prop)) {
    ProfileB[prop] = copy[prop];
  }
}

console.log(ProfileB.isAdmin());
```